# Why the variable is undefined in the show?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-7

As soon as I click to go to the show page of the musician it give me this error:
[image]

This is the show function in the Admin/MusicianController

```
public function show(Musician $musician)

    {
        return view('admin.musicians.show', compact('musician')); 
    }
```

These are the admin routes

```
Route::middleware('auth')
    ->namespace('Admin')
    ->name('admin.')
    ->prefix('admin')
    ->group(function() {

        Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('welcome');
        Route::resource('musicians', 'MusicianController'); 
    });
```

This is the link to go to the show of the musician

```
<a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{route('admin.musicians.show', $musician->id)}}">Vedi il profilo</a>
```

The place where is admin.welcome

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Musician;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Musician $musician) {
        return view('admin.welcome', compact('musician')); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error is pointing to `admin/welcome.blade.php`, but your code doesn't include where you're calling `view('admin.welcome')`.

Comment: What do you mean precisely?

Comment: @TimLewis like Tim said your `admin/welcome.blade.php` doesnt have the variable `$musician` so you need to `view('admin.welcome')` => `view('admin.welcome', compact('musician'))`

Comment: I mean your debugging tools are telling you precisely what the error is. In your `admin/welcome.blade.php`, you're referencing `$musician`, but you might not be passing the variable to that view. You didn't include any references to that file in your question, so we can only really guess. Update your question with any place you use `view('admin.welcome')` so we can help you debug further, but otherwise, you'll need to learn how to read your error message and fix it appropriately.

Comment: Edited in the answer, I put in the compact 'musician' also, now I'll try if it works

Comment: Now the question is updated, however I tried passing in the compact the musician as above with no success

Comment: "with no success" - What does that mean? Are you getting the same error? A new error? Something else? That _should_ work, `$musician` might be `null` though, which would make `$musician->id` invalid, but once again, I'm guessing as you didn't provide enough information 

Comment: Missing required parameters for [Route: admin.musicians.show] [URI: admin/musicians/{musician}]. (View: C:\Users\rober\boolean-php\bool-n-roll\resources\views\admin\welcome.blade.php)

Comment: It returns me this error

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

The changes in the Admin/HomeController

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $musician = Musician::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();

        return view('admin.musicians.index', compact('musician', 'user')); 
    }
}
```

The index function of the Admin/MusicianController, I created a new view for this (admin.musicians.index), it could have been the admin.welcome view too, but it seemed much cleaner in the controller using the index

```
public function index()
    {
        return Musician::where('user_id', Auth::id())->with('user')->get();
    }
```

The admin.musicians.index view, I used the 1 to 1 relation to catch the musician->id, both User and Musician models had hasOne() function pointing at each other

```
<div class="profile">
        <h2>Vedi il tuo profilo</h2>
        
        {{-- la rotta prende l'id del musicista legato all'utente autenticato --}}
        <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{{ route('admin.musicians.show', $user->musician->id) }}">Vedi il profilo</a>
        {{ $user->name }}
        {{$user->id}}

        {{-- questo è per capire se prendevo dati dalla relazione 1a1 --}}
        {{$user->musician->stagename}} 


        
</div>
```

The admin.musicians.show view, now I can see the name of the musicist associated with a Registered user, problem solved.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    SHOW PROFILO
    
    <h1>Nome d'arte:</h1>
    <p>{{$musician->stagename}}</p>
    
</div>
@endsection
```

Just for more info, the models

1. App\User

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','surname', 'email', 'password','address'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function musician() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Musician'); 
    }
}
```

2. App\Musician

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Musician extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 
        'stagename',
        'slug', 
        'description',
        'bio',
        'typology',
        'cover'
    ]; 

    public function user() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User'); 
    }

    public function genres() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Genre'); 
    }

    public function sponsorships() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Sponsorship'); 
    }

    public function messages() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Message'); 
    }

    public function reviews() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Review'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can 2 things :

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Musician $musician) {
         dd($musician);
        return view('admin.welcome', compact('musician')); 
    }
}
```

if dd($musician); returns nothing then write

```
class HomeController extends Controller
    {
        public function index() {
             $musician= Musician::all();
            return view('admin.welcome', compact('musician')); 
        }
    }
```

another thing

```
public function show(Musician $musician,$id)

    {
        $musician= Musician ::findOrFail($id);
        return view('admin.musicians.show', compact('musician')); 
    }
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.